# cut or grep to catch particular pattern

Tags: bash, sorting, grep, cut

i have rows like that

```
5.7015   40828240     +152             -> explode(string(1), string(21)) /f.inc:467
5.7020   40834040     +192             -> explode(string(1), string(21)) /f.inc:467
5.7020   40834088     +160             -> explode(string(1), string(21)) /f.inc:467
5.7023   40834392     +192             -> explode(string(1), string(21)) /f.inc:467
5.7027   40835000     +152             -> explode(string(1), string(21)) /f.inc:467
```

I would like to sort such output by column where numbers starting from plus (also exactly in the same columns numbers sometime can start from minus).

So somehow I need sort output by third column. I've tried `cut` for that, but i can't reach result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using coreutils sort you can do it like this (with general numeric sort order):

```
sort -k3,3g file
```

Output:

```
5.7015   40828240     +152             -> explode(string(1), string(21)) /f.inc:467
5.7027   40835000     +152             -> explode(string(1), string(21)) /f.inc:467
5.7020   40834088     +160             -> explode(string(1), string(21)) /f.inc:467
5.7020   40834040     +192             -> explode(string(1), string(21)) /f.inc:467
5.7023   40834392     +192             -> explode(string(1), string(21)) /f.inc:467
```

#### Edit - adapted for new input

If the input is as [listed by the OP](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7017985/1.xt.txt), I think some pre-filtering is needed to join related lines, something along the lines of `sed 'N; /\n *>=>/ s// >=>/; P; D'`. Taken together:

```
< 1.xt.txt sed 'N; /\n *>=>/ s// >=>/; P; D' | sort -k3,3g
```

Output:

```
TRACE START [2013-01-15 13:17:48]
    0.0149    2268328       +0       -> realpath(string(36)) /htdocs/lib/functions.inc:2 >=> '/htdocs/lib'
    0.0016     942488      +80     -> header(string(38)) /htdocs/scripts/univexport.php:8 >=> NULL
    0.0016     941816     +160     -> error_reporting(long) /htdocs/scripts/univexport.php:4 >=> 22527
    0.0016     942008     +192     -> set_time_limit(long) /htdocs/scripts/univexport.php:5 >=> TRUE
    0.0148    2268328     +264       -> dirname(string(50)) /htdocs/lib/functions.inc:2 >=> '/htdocs/lib'
    0.0016     942408     +400     -> ini_set(string(12), string(5)) /htdocs/scripts/univexport.php:6 >=> '-1'
    0.0188    2651104  +382776       -> require_once(1/htdocs/lib/functions_common.inc) /htdocs/lib/functions.inc:2
    0.0014     941656  +941656   -> {main}() /htdocs/scripts/univexport.php:0
    0.0147    2268064 +1325576     -> include_once(/htdocs/lib/functions.inc) /htdocs/scripts/univexport.php:9
```

The header is sorted to the top because it is considered a string, the general numeric order dictates the order like this (from the GNU sort manual):

> - Lines that do not start with numbers (all considered to be   equal).
> - NaNs ("Not a Number" values, in IEEE floating point   arithmetic) in a consistent but machine-dependent order.
> - Minus infinity.
> - Finite numbers in ascending numeric order (with -0 and +0   equal).
> - Plus infinity.

Comment: Thank you, on my example (it's just small piece from file) it works! but on full file (4.2Gb) it does not, maybe it because later (bellow) structure is changed or whatever :( don't know

Comment: @user1016265: you need to isolate where it fails and perhaps open a new question about how to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

sort can be told to sort on a specific column using the -k flag.

```
sort -g -k3 file
```

will sort on the third column. -t can change the field seperator which defaults to whitespace

EDIT:

Added the -g option which forces sort to use general numeric sorting

Comment: This doesn't work if there are negative numbers in the third column.

Comment: try -g which applies general numeric sorting added it into the answer too

Comment: @peteches thanks, but somehow it does not work for my original file, maybe something wrogn with whitespaces ? could you please take a look ? https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7017985/1.xt.txt

Comment: @user1016265: this input is multi-line, see the edit in my answer for one approach to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $3}' file| sed s'/+//'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you got the data in 'data.txt'.

then just use

```
sort +2 -n data.txt
```

This will sort your file beginning with the 3rd column.